# Редирект с директории на субдомен

Tags: nginx

Требуется сделать перенаправление с example.com/folder на folder.example.com. Я пробую осуществить редирект

```
location folder {    rewrite ^/(.*) http://folder.example.com$1 permanent; #301 redirect}
```

Редирект происходит, но только для example.com/folder, а не для, скажем, example.com/folder/index.html. Как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
location ~ ^/folder(.*)$ {    rewrite ^ http://folder.example.com$uri permanent;}
```

[Справка](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location) по location.